# How to load different HTML (text) in a DIV field based on user clicking on different parts of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Forgive my poorly worded title, but I don't know how to express what I'm trying to do in tech jargon.

Basically, there will be an image on the page, and when a user clicks on some part of the image, information specific to the area the user clicked on will be displayed in a "status" (prolly div container right?) next to the image. The closest thing I can reference is this link (http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Canadair_CRJ700_C.php) for SeatGuru. When a user hovers over a seat, a tooltip appears with information regarding the seat being hovered on. I'm trying to build the same functionality, but action will be a click instead of a hover and instead of information displaying in the tooltip, I want it displayed in a "status" area beside the image and refreshed every time a new "seat" is clicked on. I tried looking through the source at SeatGuru and saw jQuery references, is that how I should be trying to implement this?

Don't know if it matters, but it's being used for a Django (python) site.

TIA.

Comment: You could try image maps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: if you try to make your content dynamic, jquery is your friend, yes! with `<map>` you insert links to other targets based on a image with different "sensitive" coordinates. but you can use map to have different sensitive parts and let jquery react on it when clicked one.

Comment: i think using jquery to react on it would be what i'm trying to do, the text being displayed after the click will be coming from a database. Breaking this problem down:
1. identify what was clicked on.
2. query DB based what was clicked on.
3. return query results to page.
do you have an example or link you could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also easily use an image map creator which avoids a lot of work here ;)
e.g:
http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/

Comment: I like this, but how can I query an API based on what area the user clicks? An ajax/javascript call in either the href or target field?

Comment: here you just need to upload the image --> click accept
left mouse key on the image to define the rect.

After this you can just use the embedded code below and add the needed href.

To query the clicks I would try to give an Id or class to each area and track this clicks with js

Answer (score 0):

You can define clickable areas in image using HTML image maps:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Another option is using SVG image with hyperlinks

Comment: How would I tie in a javascript/ajax API call?